# JoinEvent discord JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a trouble coding JoinEvent in java using JDA. I writed code and added the listener in main file, but it doesn't works. **Code:**

```
    User user = event.getUser();
    String servername = event.getGuild().getName();

    EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
    eb.setDescription("Witaj, " + event.getMember().getAsMention());
    eb.setImage(user.getAvatarUrl());
    eb.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    eb.addField("Witamy na serwerze " + servername, "Mamy nadzieje że zostaniesz z nami dłużej ;)", true);
    eb.setFooter(event.getGuild().getIconUrl() + "Jesteś " + event.getGuild().getMembers() + " osobą na naszym serwerze!");

    event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1187722804620177438").sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).queue();
```

I tried making a `TextChannel channel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1187722804620177438")` **and** `channel.sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).queue();` **instand of** `event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1187722804620177438").sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).queue();`

I expected a message on channel with id "1187722804620177438"

Comment: Is it showing any errors...?

Comment: question needs more detail. please provide a stack trace or more detailed context

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code hereimport net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.member.GuildMemberJoinEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.awt.Color;

public class WelcomeListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        String servername = event.getGuild().getName();
        String welcomeChannelId = "1187722804620177438"; // Setze die ID deines Begrüßungskanals hier ein

        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
        eb.setDescription("Witaj, " + event.getMember().getAsMention());
        eb.setImage(event.getUser().getAvatarUrl());
        eb.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        eb.addField("Witamy na serwerze " + servername, "Mamy nadzieję, że zostaniesz z nami dłużej ;)", true);
        eb.setFooter("Jesteś " + event.getGuild().getMemberCount() + " osobą na naszym serwerze!", event.getGuild().getIconUrl());

        event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(welcomeChannelId).sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).queue();
    }
}
```